# VSIX - Cannot load file or assembly of a referenced dll

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vsix, vspackage

My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12110135/vsix-package-doesnt-include-referenced-projects-dependencies), only that the answer and work-around are not working for me.  Also I am in Visual Studio 2012.

I have a VSPackage which is referencing another project, which is dependent on other dlls.  Everytime time I run my package in debug I get an exception that the other dlls cannot be found.  They are in the output directory, and they are signed.

I tried referencing them directly by the VSPackage project to no avail.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This problem exists because Visual Studio is not looking for assemblies in a folder of your extension if your extension has no explicit dependence on these assemblies. For example, dependences set in a configuration file (IoC config) or in xaml code. I know three solutions to this problem:

1. You can deploy these assemblies in the GAC and Visual Studio will load them. This method is good if you use a third-party library that built for use in the GAC (for example, MS Enterprise Library). But [VSIX Deployment Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff363239.aspx) does not allow installing assemblies in the GAC, you can use the MSI installer.
2. For VSPackages for Visual Studio 2010/2012 you can use [ProvideBindingPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg590213%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) attribute. The path where your extension located will be added to the paths that Visual Studio uses to find dependent assemblies. If your extension doesn't include a VSPackage, you can add this attribute to any public class ([see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg590213(v=vs.100).aspx)).

   ```cs
   [ProvideBindingPath] 
   public class MyVsPackage : Package 
   { /* ... */ }
   ```
3. You can manually resolve assembly names. To do this, you need to subscribe to the AssemblyResolve event and you need to return required assemblies from a handler. This is the most flexible way, if you cannot use the previous methods, this is especially for you.

   In my IntelliDebugger project, I wrote a class ManualAssemblyResolver for it:

```cs
using System;
using System.Reflection;
    
namespace IntelliEgg.Debugger.Utility
{
    public class ManualAssemblyResolver : IDisposable
    {
        public ManualAssemblyResolver(Assembly assembly)
        {
            if (assembly == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("assembly");

            _assemblies = new[] {assembly};
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += OnAssemblyResolve;
        }

        public ManualAssemblyResolver(params Assembly[] assemblies)
        {
            if (assemblies == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("assemblies");

            if (assemblies.Length == 0)
                throw new ArgumentException("Assemblies should be not empty.", "assemblies");

            _assemblies = assemblies;
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += OnAssemblyResolve;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve -= OnAssemblyResolve;
        }

        private Assembly OnAssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            foreach (Assembly assembly in _assemblies)
            {
                if (args.Name == assembly.FullName)
                {
                    return assembly;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        private readonly Assembly[] _assemblies;
    }
}
```

This class must be created before the first call to the problem assembly (e.g., in Package::Initialize() method)

Comment: How did you load the assemblies to pass into this utility class? Rather... what context did you use? `Assembly.LoadFrom(filename)`? I am wondering how you protect the same version of an assembly from being loaded by another plugin in another context?

Comment: Yes I use `Assembly.LoadFrom()` or `typeof(ClassFromMyAssembly).Assembly` and a reference to `MyAssembly` in the project (for `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll`). The purpose of using `ManualAssemblyResolver` allows Visual Studio to load all dependent assemblies from any folder and explicitly determine it in your code. To support modularity I use MS Prism and configure modules loading in the `Bootstrapper` class.

Comment: 2. Worked for me. Can it bring problems if other extensions also provide the path and use the same libraries?

Comment: #2 solved my problem in VS2017. It was working without it for years but no it was suddenly required. I don't understand why.