# How to deploy SQLServer CE for VSPackage?

Tags: sql-server, vspackage

I like to deploy SQLServer CE privately on my VSPackage application. 
I already tried the following information:

[Using Entity Framework with an SQL Compact Private Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540784/using-entity-framework-with-an-sql-compact-private-installation)

as well as this one:

[How to deploy SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739845/how-to-deploy-sql-server-compact-edition-4-0)

But I still get the following exception message:

```
The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid
```

I guess the above methods do not work for me because my VSPackage will appear as a DLL, while the above methods work for an .EXE application.

Any suggestion how can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, Visual Studio cannot find and load one of SQL Server Compact Edition assemblies. By default, Visual Studio don’t look dependent assembles in a VSPackage folder if VSPackage code have not explicit reference to such assembles. I described several ways to solve this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13765842/1815957). Hope it help you.