# Extended WPF Toolkit in VS 2013 Package: Could not load file or assembly

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2013, package, visual-studio-extensions

I am developing a Visual Studio 2013 Package.

I've used [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/) to get the [Extended WPF Toolkit](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) and added a `CheckComboBox` to one of my `UserControl`.

When I debug the VS Experimental Hive, the user control cannot load because an exception is shown in the XAML editor, right before the `CheckComboBox` declaration.

The declaration:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="EditorControl"
    xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
    ...
    />

<xctk:CheckComboBox
    Delimiter=";"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ApplicabilityValues}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Applicability}"
    SelectedItemsOverride="{Binding SelectedItems}"
    />
```

The exception:

> XamlParseException
>
> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit, PublicKeyToken=3e4669d2f30244f4' or one of its
>   dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))

The inner exception

> ArgumentException
>
> The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057
>   (E_INVALIDARG))

Things I tried so far:

- I've added all Extended WPF Toolkit libraries in the `.vsixmanifest` file as Assets, so now the libraries are added to the solution itself and they are marked with `CopyAlways=True` and `BuildAction=Content`, but the exception stays.
- I've cleared the `bin/Debug` and the `C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Temp` folders.
- I've reseted the VS Experimental Hive enviroment.

Nothing has worked out so far.

### What do I have to do to get the Extended WPF Toolkit to work in a Visual Studio 2013 Package?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by using the attribute `[ProvideBindingPath]` over my Package class.

I am not sure about the implications this has with other extensions using Extended WPF Toolkit though.

I found it thanks to the support from https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/discussions/642398#post1437746

And the stackoverflow link where the attribute was proposed: [VSIX - Cannot load file or assembly of a referenced dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674782/vsix-cannot-load-file-or-assembly-of-a-referenced-dll)