# VSIX not installing dependencies in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vsix

I've been developing a small Visual Studio extension (purely for in-house use) and it consists of the VSIX project itself, which then references another dll (in the same solution) that then references some other project (also in the same solution). This all works fine when I debug the extension and run it in the experimental instance of Visual Studio. However, if I try to install the VSIX in Visual Studio for real (by double clicking the `.vsix` file) It does not work. There is one command that doesn't reference anything from the other assemblies that works fine and then there is another command that does that just fails silently.

Looking at the installation under `C:\Users\matt.burland\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0Exp\Extensions` and `C:\Users\matt.burland\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Extensions` I can see the difference is that the other dependencies where not installed by the VSIX.

I saw this question for VS2010: [VSIX package doesn't include localized resources of referenced assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974244/vsix-package-doesnt-include-localized-resources-of-referenced-assembly)

But the solution there doesn't seem to be relevant. I don't see an `Output Groups Included in VSIX` property to set.

I tried looking at `source.extension.vsixmanifest` and it has a tab for dependencies. I selected `New`, Selected `A project in current solution` as source, selected one of my projects, selected `Embed in this VSIX`, but when I click `Ok` I get an error message:

> VSIX Manifest Editor
>
> No Extenders could be found for the name 'VsixProjectReferenceContentItemObjectExtender' under the CATID {2F0FA3B8-C855-4a4e-95A5-CB45C67D6C27}. Make sure that the extender provider for this Extender is correctly registered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I should be looking at assets rather than dependencies, but I was unable to add as an asset using the manifest editor either with a similar error. So I created an entirely new, empty VSIX project in a new solution, added an empty class library, referenced it in the VSIX project and then looked at the manifest editor. For whatever reason, I was able to add the assembly without any problem.

Then looking at the `.vsixmanifest` file in the XML editor, I could figure out the correct syntax to reference an assembly and copy it to my real project. For the record (because the documentation on the `.vsixmanifest` isn't at all informative here), it looks like this:

```
<Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Assembly" d:Source="Project" d:ProjectName="MyProject" 
       Path="|MyProject|" AssemblyName="|MyProject;AssemblyName|" />
```

Where `MyProject` is the name of the dependent class library in your solution that needs to be included in the VSIX.